# Django Template Attributes of QuerySet for ManyToMany with "Through" Class

Tags: python, django, templates

I've got roughly models like these:

```
class Person(models.Model):
  ...
  name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
  eyes = models.CharField(max_length=12)
  ...
  relationships = models.ManyToManyField('self', through='Relationship',
    symmetrical=False, related_name='related_to')

class Relationship(models.Model):
  from_person = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='from_people', ...)
  to_person = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='to_people', ...)
  status = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

I've got reasonable database entries, and can see them in the Python shell:

```
>>> p1 = Person.objects.get(...)
>>> r = Relationship.objects.filter(from_person=p1)
<QuerySet [<Relationship: p1 p2 status>], [<Relationship: p1 p99 status>]>
>>> r[0].status
Friend
>>> r[0].from_person.name
p1
>>> r[0].from_person.eyes
Brown    # p1's eye color
>>> r[0].to_person.name
p2
>>> r[0].to_person.eyes
Blue    # p2's eye color !!!
```

Now I want to access this same information from my templates, but I don't see what I expect:

```
<p>name={{ person.name }} ({{ person.eyes }})</p>
<p>len={{ person.relationships.all|length }}</p>
{% for rel in person.relationships.all %}
  <p> rel[{{ forloop.counter }}]={{ rel.status }}
        {{ rel.from_person.name }} ({{ rel.from_person.eyes }})
        {{ rel.to_person.name }}   ({{ rel.to_person.eyes }})</p>
{% endfor %}
```

This displays:

```
name=p1 (Brown)
len=2
rel[0]=
rel[1]=
```

I expect:

```
name=p1 (Brown)
len=2
rel[0]=Friend p1 (Brown) p2 (Blue)
rel[1]=Enemy p1 (Brown) p99 (Red!)
```

I added accessor methods to the 'Relationship' model, but it didn't make a difference.
I messed with using the template "slice" filter.
I'm missing something basic...

Thanks for your help!

edit:  This template code does what I want for the example above.  Thanks to the two commenters below:

```
{% for rel in person.from_people.all %}
  <p> rel[{{ forloop.counter }}]={{ rel.status }}
        {{ rel.from_person.name }} ({{ rel.from_person.eyes }})
        {{ rel.to_person.name   }} ({{ rel.to_person.eyes   }})</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This template code does what I want for the example above. Thanks to the two commenters:

```
{% for rel in person.from_people.all %}
  <p> rel[{{ forloop.counter }}]={{ rel.status }}
        {{ rel.from_person.name }} ({{ rel.from_person.eyes }})
        {{ rel.to_person.name   }} ({{ rel.to_person.eyes   }})</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this line of code in your `Person`model:

`relationships = models.ManyToManyField('self', through='Relationship', ...)`

If you address the attribute `relationships` of a `Person`instance, it returns a Manager for the target model (which is also `Person`).

So `p1.relationships.all()` returns all *persons* that `p1` is related to, not the Relationship instances.

If you want to access the intermediate data of your `through`model, you have to directly query it:

`Relationship.objects.filter(from_person=p1)`

See also the examples in the [Docs (Django 2.0): *Extra fields on many-to-many relationships*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany)

**Edit**: Dan's comment might show the correct way to access the Relationship data given a Person from the template. I think the template language should be able to handle backward relations. Can you try this and tell if it works?

```
<p>name={{ person.name }} ({{ person.eyes }})</p>
<p>len={{ person.relationships.all|length }}</p>
{% for rel in person.from_people.all %}
  {# rel is now a Relationship where 'from_person' is 'person' #}
  <p> rel[{{ forloop.counter }}]={{ rel.status }}
        {{ rel.from_person.name }} ({{ rel.from_person.eyes }})
        {{ rel.to_person.name }}   ({{ rel.to_person.eyes }})</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can't you use the `related_name` defined in the `Relationship` foreign keys,  like `rel.from_people.all` or `rel.to_people.all`? I'm not sure which one would give the desired result, but I'm pretty sure one of those would do it.

Comment: OP here:  I can get the results that I want when I am in the python shell.  See above.  The issue is in my templates.  It's important to note, and maybe you're on to something here, that in my template, if I put `{{ person.relationships.all }}` I do get a QueryList of Person objects returned.  I can get all the attributes of each person, but I'll have to build an accessor to find the `status` attribute.

Comment: ascripter/Dan:  I'll try your edit tonight or tomorrow. Yesterday, I pushed ahead by just using the "Person" attributes, and not the "status".  I understand what you and Dan are suggesting and will reply back here likely tomorrow.  Thanks for your help!